# JSON parse generates url-encoded strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, json

I never noticed this behavior before, but when parsing a JSON-encoded string saved in a cookie, the strings seem url-encoded (mainly the symptom is the spaces are replaced with the plus "+" sign).

Basically it's an array of flash messages (as in Rails, I'm not sure if the problem is on the encoding side) encoded using:

```
def write_flash_to_cookie
  cookie_flash = {}

  flash.each do |key, value|
    if cookie_flash[key.to_s].nil? or cookie_flash[key.to_s].blank?
        cookie_flash[key.to_s]= [value]
    else
        cookie_flash[key.to_s]<< value
    end
  end

  cookies['flash']= cookie_flash.to_json
  flash.clear
end
```

And displayed as such:

```
if($.cookie('flash')) {
  var flash= $.parseJSON($.cookie('flash'));

  for(type in flash) {
    for(message in flash[type]) {
      $('#flash').append("<div class=\"" + type + "\">" + flash[type][message] + "</div>");
    }
  }
}
```

I don't see what I'm missing here...

Comment: The problem lies in Ruby's (or Rails in this instance, since to_json uses ActiveSupport) cookie support, which URL-encodes strings. The only solution so far seems to simply to a RegEx replace for the '+' sign.

Answer (score 0):

try .html_safe on the end of the string. I believe this has helped me in the past with this exact issue.

Comment: Tried but it doesn't change anything.